# How to retrive data from Multiple JSON response object

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am having following Arraylist

```
        JSONArray JMyDataList= new JSONArray(MyDataList);
        JSONArray JMyProjectData = new JSONArray(MyProjectData);
```

MyDataList: contains data from database with column name & data

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
out = response.getWriter();
out.println(JMyDataList+"\n");
out.println(JMyProjectData );
out.close();
```

In javascript i am able to see response object,`alert(xmlHttp.responseText);` `CREATED_DATE` is column name in MyDataList

```
var sampleJSON =xmlHttp.responseText;
var parsed_data = JSON.parse(sampleJSON);
alert(parsed_data.CREATED_DATE);
```

json object

```
[{"CREATED_DATE":"1/12/2014","USER_ID":"DUMMY_SU"}]
[{"PROJ_NAME":"PROJ1"},{"PROJ_NAME":"PROJ2"},{"PROJ_NAME":"PROJ3"},{"PROJ_NAME":"PROJ4"}]
```

How can access individual column values from this object and assign to textbox on html page?

How to retrive PROJ_NAME Array ?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON into an object and then access the values in the object as normal.

Comment: What does the returned JSON actually look like?

Answer (score 1):

parsed_data is an Array of objects.

```
<script>
for(var i=0; i<parsed_data.length; i++){
alert(parsed_data[i].CREATED_DATE);
}
</script>
```

UPDATED 04.12.2014

I'm not sure what kind of platform you have on server side.

MVC part:

```
public class Person{
    public Id int {get; set;}
    public Name string {get; set;}
}

public JsonResult MyActionName()
{
    var object1 = new { Prop1="This is property 1", CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Today};

    List<Person> persList = new List<Person>();
    persList.Add(new Person(){Name = "Alex1", Id = 1});
    persList.Add(new Person(){Name = "Alex2", Id = 2});
    persList.Add(new Person(){Name = "Alex3", Id = 3});
    persList.Add(new Person(){Name = "Alex4", Id = 4});

    var result = new { _myObject = object1, _myList = persList};

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Javascript part:
// with jquery because it's easier

```
<script>

$.ajax({
    url: "MyActionName",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        var object1 = data._myObject; 
        // object1 = { Prop1: "This is property 1", CREATED_DATE:  "some date string"}

        var _person;
        for(var i=0; i<data._myList.length; i++){
            _person = data._myList[i];
            // _person = {Name: "Alex1", Id: 1}
            // _person = {Name: "Alex2", Id: 2}
            // _person = {Name: "Alex3", Id: 3}
            // _person = {Name: "Alex4", Id: 4}
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: How to get and parse  multiple json objects into response?

Comment: You just create arrays of objects. If you returning data from MVC controller, you can set the return type as JsonResult and use return Json(object) to return any kind of object that you need. It can be a List<object> or dynamic or whatever

Comment: could you please explain with example